# Getting names from a Javascript Object inside multiple other Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I am really struggling to get to the names in this javascript object. Please could someone help me? What I want is to get someones name and if their "attending' status is true push their name into the "going" array and if their status is false push their name into the "not going" array.

The object is below and then the code I have written so far is below that. I don't know what to do when I get to the name level as they're different names...

```js
"HmS7XXPFoCQ7GmvfcCnF": {
            "invitees": {
                "gus": {
                    "attending": true,
                    "invitedBy": "will"
                },
                "margot": {
                    "attending": "false",
                    "invitedBy": "gus"
                }
            }
        }
```

here is my code:

```js
        Object.keys(invitees).map(function(keyName, i) {
            if (invitees[keyName] === true) {
                //this is causing problems as the last name will be displayed as august,
                inviteesGoing.push(`${keyName}, `);
            } else if (invitees[keyName] === false) {
                //this is causing problems as the last name will be displayed as august,
                inviteesNotGoing.push(`${keyName}, `);
            } else {
                console.error("undetermind user status:" + keyName);
            }
        });
```

thanks

Comment: Just want to point out, your JSON is showing `margot.attending = “false”` which is a strong but you are comparing it to `false` as a Boolean in your if statement.

Comment: Why are you putting commas in the array? If you want comma separators, add them when you use `.join`

Comment: If you use `map()` and the function doesn't return anything and you don't use the result, you should be using `forEach()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've extended your example object a little bit and using a simple `forEach` solve your problem. You can try this:

```js
const data = {
  "invitees": {"gus": {"attending": true, "invitedBy": "will"}, "margot": {"attending": false, "invitedBy": "gus"}, "John": {"attending": true, "invitedBy": "gus"}, "doe": {"attending": true, "invitedBy": "John"}, "Alex": {"attending": false, "invitedBy": "John"}}
 };

const going = [], notGoing = [];

Object.entries(data.invitees).forEach(([name, value]) => {
    if (value.attending) {
 going.push(name);
    } else {
 notGoing.push(name);
    }
});

console.log('going', going);
console.log('not going', notGoing);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use reduce to keep both array. And while pushing data, add more details like `attending, invitedBy`. Use `Object.entries`, better control than `Object.keys`

```js
const findInfo = (invitees) => {
  return Object.entries(invitees).reduce(
    ([going, notgoing], [name, { attending, invitedBy }]) => {
      let map = attending === true ? going : notgoing;
      map.push({
        name,
        attending,
        invitedBy,
      });
      return [going, notgoing];
    },
    [[], []]
  );
};
const findInfoWithout = (invitees) => {
  const [going, notgoing] = [[], []];
  Object.entries(invitees).forEach(([name, { attending, invitedBy }]) => {
    let map = attending === true ? going : notgoing;
    map.push({
      name,
      attending,
      invitedBy,
    });
  });
  return [going, notgoing];
};
const data = {
  HmS7XXPFoCQ7GmvfcCnF: {
    invitees: {
      gus: {
        attending: true,
        invitedBy: "will",
      },
      margot: {
        attending: "false",
        invitedBy: "gus",
      },
    },
  },
};

console.log(findInfo(data.HmS7XXPFoCQ7GmvfcCnF.invitees));
console.log(findInfoWithout(data.HmS7XXPFoCQ7GmvfcCnF.invitees));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do it using [mapValues](https://lodash.com/docs/#mapValues) in lodash :

```
const going = [];
const notGoing = [];

const guests = {
 "invitees": {
   "major": {
      "attending": true,
      "invitedBy": "will"
    },
   "tom": {
      "attending": true,
      "invitedBy": "gus"
     },
   "Ben": {
      "attending": false,
      "invitedBy": "gus"
    }
   }
};

_.mapValues(guests.invitees, (obj, guestName) => {
  obj.attending ? going.push(guestName) : notGoing.push(guestName)
})
console.log(going)
console.log(notGoing)
```